# How to import seaborn in Python?

Tags: python-3.x

I am getting an error with importing seaborn. Does anybody know what I did wrong?
 import seaborn as sns

ImportError: No module named 'seaborn'

Comment: It's not built-in; you'll have to install it.

Comment: I did. I am getting an error while I install it

Comment: We can't help you with that if you don't show us what you tried and what happened.

Answer (score 2):

You have to install it first.

`pip install seaborn`

If you are using python3 and have both p2 and p3 installed then

`pip3 install seaborn`

You can confirm the import by executing

`python -c "import seaborn"` or `python3`