# No module named seaborn even if I installed it

Tags: python, seaborn, git-bash, python-poetry

I got a problem with seaborn. When I run **poetry**, the shell said that No module named 'seaborn' even I install it by pip install seaborn:

```
$ pip install seaborn
Requirement already satisfied: seaborn in c:\users\administrator\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages (0.10.0)
Requirement already satisfied: scipy>=1.0.1 in c:\users\administrator\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages (from seaborn) (1.4.1)
Requirement already satisfied: matplotlib>=2.1.2 in c:\users\administrator\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages (from seaborn) (3.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pandas>=0.22.0 in c:\users\administrator\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages (from seaborn) (1.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.13.3 in c:\users\administrator\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages (from seaborn) (1.18.1)
Requirement already satisfied: cycler>=0.10 in c:\users\administrator\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib>=2.1.2->seaborn) (0.10.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pyparsing!=2.0.4,!=2.1.2,!=2.1.6,>=2.0.1 in c:\users\administrator\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib>=2.1.2->seaborn) (2.4.6)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.1 in c:\users\administrator\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib>=2.1.2->seaborn) (2.8.1)
Requirement already satisfied: kiwisolver>=1.0.1 in c:\users\administrator\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib>=2.1.2->seaborn) (1.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=2017.2 in c:\users\administrator\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages (from pandas>=0.22.0->seaborn) (2019.3)
Requirement already satisfied: six in c:\users\administrator\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages (from cycler>=0.10->matplotlib>=2.1.2->seaborn) (1.14.0)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in c:\users\administrator\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages (from kiwisolver>=1.0.1->matplotlib>=2.1.2->seaborn) (41.2.0)
```

When I check the import as this question: [How to import seaborn in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50611287/how-to-import-seaborn-in-python) (by `python -c "import seaborn"`), the shell run in about 8 - 10 seconds but nothing appear next.

What is the problem? What should I do to fix it error? Do I install seaborn properly? I'm using Windows, git bash as shell and Python 3.8.2.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using poetry as a dependency manager, you need to install the dependency for the poetry virtual environment.

Just add a line in the `pyproject.toml` file under the:

```
[tool.poetry.dependencies]
seaborn = "^0.9.0"
```

And then run the command `poetry install`. The next time you run your project, it will have seaborn installed in the environment the project is running.

Comment: I use "poetry run python -m pip install seaborn", add your line and it fixed, but I think use only "poetry run python -m pip install seaborn" is ok since I must "update" seaborn from version 0.10.0 to 0.9.1 (I think the cause is the line "^0.9.0").